# How to print query output in Html using google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
Entity Kind :Football

Entity Key :ag9kZXZ-YWNxdWl0d29ybGRyFQsSCEZvb3RiYWxsGICAgICA8IsKDA

ID : 5681726336532480

email (string)
manutd@gmail.com

identity (string)
Manchester United
```

This is the data in my datastore. Now I want to search the details based on the `input(Emailid)`. So, if I input the email detail, I want to fetch the corresponding club name and print it on `Html` page. I have written the following code

```
class searchApp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #self.response.out.write(que)
        name=self.request.get('last_name')
        player_key=Football.query()
        #qry=Football.Key(5891733057437696)
        qry=player_key.filter(Football.email==name)
        #for qry2 in qry:
        self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % qry.identity())
```

From what I understood, `qry` is a object, so I need to use for loop and print the result as in `qry2.email`, `qry2.identity`. But for some reason, I am not able to do so hence I commented that part. Need to know how to fetch the details.

I got the following error :

```
self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % qry.identity())
```

AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'identity'
     How can that be possible as my Model function has email and identity.

Comment: There's both too much and not enough information here. Too much because you have included your whole script, instead of just the relevant parts. But not enough because you say "for some reason" you can't do it: for *what* reason? What happens? What errors do you get? Where do they occur?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with relevant information.  When I submit the 'email' through text field, I am getting the error as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If identify is a field on your model then it does not need to be called with () as it's not a function.

This is wrong:

```
identity = qry.identity()
```

this is right:

```
identity = qry.identity
```

But that won't work because you have a query object, not a model. Take another look at the documentation

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass

```
q = db.Query(Song)
for song in q:
  print song.title
```

Not that `song.title` is not expressed as `song.title()`

You can only write to the response once so you need something like:

```
q = db.Query(Song)
data = []
for song in q:
  data.append(song.title)
self.response.out.write(','.join(data))
```

That'll just stick together the list of titles into a single string separated by commas.

Take another look at the documentation. Your problem is practically the same as their example.